# How can I get Firebase Storage data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

[image]

This is how my Firebase storage look like, i want get these files name but im not able to do so,
Im sharing my code below,

```
const files = firebase.storage().ref(`pdf`);
                console.log(files)
                files.getDownloadURL().then((files) => {
                    console.log(files);
                })
```

If im giving exactly Name, then im able to get the file, like,

```
const files = firebase.storage().ref('pdf/5b8e28a8-fe06-4312-9ff6-3c9adfefb2b3.pdf/');
        files.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          //console.log(url);
          window.open(url, "_blank")
        })
      }
```

And im getting this error in console,

[image]

Can anyone explain what im doing wrong here

Comment: Use the list API to list files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, to [get a list of the files/subfolders](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files), you use `listAll()`.

To get the list of files in the PDF folder:

```
// Create a reference under which you want to list
const files = firebase.storage().ref('pdf');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
files.listAll().then(function(res) {
  Promise.all(res.items.map((fileRef) => fileRef.getDownloadURL())).then((downloadURLs) => {
    console.log(downloadURLs);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank, but im getting error that listAll() is not a function.

Comment: That typically means that you're on an SDK version that doesn't include the functionality to list files yet. You'll want to upgrade to the latest SDK version.